# AWS::Lambda::Permission vs AWS::IAM::Role to give API Gateway permission to invoke Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm programatically building a CloudFormation template that sets up API Gateway and Lambda functions to serve HTTP requests. Everything is going well and I am successfully provisioning both services and tying them together, but currently API Gateway doesn't have permission to invoke my Lambda functions which is causing an `Internal Server Error` response.

In Googling how to grant this permission I came across two ways to do it.

### First way: `AWS::Lambda::Permission`

[As we can see from this example I came across](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/c314952045eee8e8375b82bc7ec68e88#file-stack-yaml-L72-L80), I can create a `AWS::Lambda::Permission` resource that allows API Gateway to invoke my function:

```
  lambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${apiGateway}/${apiGatewayStageName}/${apiGatewayHTTPMethod}/
```

### Second way: `AWS::IAM::Role`

[I also stumbled on this article](https://nickolaskraus.io/articles/creating-an-amazon-api-gateway-with-a-lambda-integration-using-cloudformation/) which gives API Gateway permission to invoke the Lambda using an IAM role:

```
  ApiGatewayIamRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: ''
            Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: '/'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LambdaAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Action: 'lambda:*'
                Resource: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
```

My question is, which way is best? `AWS::Lambda::Permission` seems easiest if all I want to do is give API Gateway permission to invoke my functions, but `AWS::IAM::Role` seems like it'd give me more flexibility in future by being able to add additional permissions down the line.

Do I have that correct? Is there a best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use what [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-permissions) recommend to use, which is `resource-based policy`:

> Amazon API Gateway gets permission to invoke your function from the function's **resource-based policy**.

This way, you can indicate that lambda function is in charge of its own interactions permissions.